# VSCode task executes in wrong directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I created a folder in my user directory, `C:\Users\myname\someproject`

I then created a task in this folder

```json
// C:\Users\myname\someproject\.vscode\tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "show project dir",
            "type": "shell",
            "command":"pwd",
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this task, I get the following output

```
> Executing task: pwd <


Path
----
C:\Users\myname



Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I was expecting it to print the directory of the project, not my home directory. Why is it not printing out the project dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my powershell "profile" ran this command:

```
# C:\Users\myname\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1
Set-Location ~
```

So whenever a terminal was launched (including when a task is run) then the terminal cd'ed to home directory.